# How to fit a nonlinear equation to a given input and output signal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Assume a nonlinear system

```
y(t) = a*u(t) + b*du(t)/dt + c*(u(t))^2
```

where the input signal u(t) is a sweep and the output signal y(t) is calculated in `Simulink` for chosen values of the parameters *(a, b, c)*.

What is the suited `Matlab` toolbox/function to estimate the parameters based on the signals *u(t)* and *y(t)*?

I've found [`lsqcurvefit`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) that can be used to fit a model to *(t, y(t))*, but I do not think it can be applied to the described case *(u(t), y(t))*?

Comment: If you have the values for `y`, `u` and `du/dt` for the same values of `t`, a vector, then the simplest way to determine the parameters `a`, `b` and `c`, since it is a linear regression, is to use [`mldivide`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). For instance, `t = 0:0.01:1;` `u = sin(100*t.^2);` `u2 = u .^2;` `du = 200*t.*cos(100*t.^2);` and let's say you take `y = 5 * u + 10 * u2 + 0.01 * du;` . Then retrieving the three parameters (5, 10 and 0.01) through the least squares method is as simple as `[u; u2; du]' \ y'`